# QLocale, from Language name to language code (2 letter)

Tags: c++, qt

In QLocale,

How to find the 'two-letter, ISO 639 language code' from the language name?
 For example, 'English', its two-letter code is: en.
'Chinese', its two-letter code is: zh

If I know the language name, e.g. "English", do we have a function to return its two-letter code, e.g. 'en'?

I looked at the 'QLocale' class and did not find a method for this purpose.

Comment: English is only the language name (of English) in English ... so you have a problem with the premise.  It's a many to 1 mapping.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing provided - you'll need to search through the available locales.  Do you really need to convert in this direction, though?  Most code will work with ISO 639 codes internally, and only need to convert when presenting to users.  If you can arrange for the user to select from a list, then that list should be using the language code internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate all locales to find an instance you need and then use `bcp47Name()` method

```
QString strLang = "Chinese";
QList<QLocale> allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(QLocale::AnyLanguage, QLocale::AnyScript, QLocale::AnyCountry);
for (int iLocale = 0; iLocale < allLocales.count(); iLocale++)
{
    if (QLocale::languageToString(allLocales.at(iLocale).language()) == strLang)
    {
        if (allLocales.at(iLocale).bcp47Name().length() == 2) {
            qDebug() << allLocales.at(iLocale).bcp47Name();
        }
    }
}
```